# Managing memory of Vector3's created to move gameObject

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, unity-game-engine

I'm coming from a C++ background and am new to both C# as well as Unity5 Game Engine.

I'm currently working through some of the tutorial projects ([Space Shooter](http://unity3d.com/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player)) and have a doubt about memory management.

Consider this code to apply user input to move the player gameObject:

```
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
       float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
       float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

       Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
       rigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;

      /* additional logic */
   }
```

My questions are basically:

1. Wouldn't this create a new Vector3 struct for every physics frame that the user is providing input?
2. How is this memory managed and cleared, can it be explicitly handled without relying on some automatic garbage collection?
3. Does the process of assigning it to a rigidbody somehow consume the struct and remove it from memory, or maybe these temp structs are cleared at the end of FixedUpdate()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It creates a new `Vector3` every `FixedUpdate()` (60 times per second, by default), even if user is not providing input.
2. `Vector3` created on a stack. And releasing once you left function. (No garbage collection)
3. When you assign a variable `movement` to `rigidbody.velocity`, you are simply copying struct. (No garbage collection)

If you think about `new` operator. For structures it does not instantiate an object in a heap. It is a way to call constructor and initialize fields.

Comment: Worth noting for the OP that `Vector3` is a `struct` not a `class` - the variable holds a value-type as opposed to a pointer to an object. Structs are typically created on the stack and deallocated when they leaves scope; it's also copy-passed between functions by default.